# Есть 3 <select>. В каждом одинаковый состав. Как убирать выбранный пользователем элемент из двух других?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select

```
<select id="1" class="form-control form-control-sm">
  <option>Вариант 1</option>
  <option>Вариант 2</option>
  <option>Вариант 3</option>
</select>

<select id="2" class="form-control form-control-sm">
  <option>Вариант 1</option>
  <option>Вариант 2</option>
  <option>Вариант 3</option>
</select>

<select id="3" class="form-control form-control-sm">
  <option>Вариант 1</option>
  <option>Вариант 2</option>
  <option>Вариант 3</option>
</select>
```

Допустим, я в select с id 1 выберу Вариант 2, и он должен убраться из двух других (id 2 и 3).

Comment: Написать скрипт, очевидно. В чём трудность?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Везде добавлена первая выбранная по дефолту пустая опция... отключенная для дальнейшего выбора. Сделано для того, чтобы событие 'change' правильно срабатывало. Можно было просто дать им `display: none;`

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/sbpa4erk/)

```js
(function(){

let select = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control');
for(let i = 0; i < select.length; i++){
  /* На все селекты по классу, вешаем событие "change" и запускаем функцию каждый раз, 
  когда меняется выбранная опция */
  select[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
    let index = select[i].selectedIndex; /* получаем номер выбранной опции */
    
    /* ненужное демо */
    console.clear();
    console.log( index );
    
    /* перебрав все селекты, внутри них делаем невидимыми все опции, которые по номеру  
    совпадают с текущим выбранным [index] */
    for(let u = 0; u < select.length; u++){
      select[u].getElementsByTagName('option')[index].style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}

document.getElementById('reset').onclick = function(){
  for(let i = 0; i < select.length; i++){
    select[i].value = 'Выберите...';
    let option = select[i].getElementsByTagName('option');
    for(let u = 0; u < option.length; u++){
      /* При клике на сброс - возвращаем опции на место. */
      option[u].style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
};

})();
```

```html
<select id="1" class="form-control form-control-sm" >
  <option disabled selected>Выберите...</option>
  <option>Вариант 1</option>
  <option>Вариант 2</option>
  <option>Вариант 3</option>
</select>

<select id="2" class="form-control form-control-sm">
  <option disabled selected>Выберите...</option>
  <option>Вариант 1</option>
  <option>Вариант 2</option>
  <option>Вариант 3</option>
</select>

<select id="3" class="form-control form-control-sm">
  <option disabled selected>Выберите...</option>
  <option>Вариант 1</option>
  <option>Вариант 2</option>
  <option>Вариант 3</option>
</select>

<button id="reset">Сброс</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

```js
let s = [...document.querySelectorAll('select')];
s.forEach(e => e.onchange = () => {
  let t = e.options[e.selectedIndex].textContent
  t && s.filter(o => e !== o)
        .forEach(o => [...o.options].find(o => o.textContent===t).style.display = "none")
});
```

```html
<select id="1" class="form-control form-control-sm">
  <option></option>
  <option>Вариант 1</option>
  <option>Вариант 2</option>
  <option>Вариант 3</option>
</select>

<select id="2" class="form-control form-control-sm">
  <option></option>
  <option>Вариант 1</option>
  <option>Вариант 2</option>
  <option>Вариант 3</option>
</select>

<select id="3" class="form-control form-control-sm">
  <option></option>
  <option>Вариант 1</option>
  <option>Вариант 2</option>
  <option>Вариант 3</option>
</select>
```

---

UPD: вот такой вариант, выбранный пункт прячется у всех, если отменить выбор появляется обратно...

```js
let selects = [...document.querySelectorAll('select')];
selects.forEach(e => e.onchange = () => {
  let selected = selects.map(e => e.options[e.selectedIndex].textContent).filter(d => d);
  selects.forEach(o => [...o.options].forEach(option => {
    option.style.display = ~selected.indexOf(option.textContent) ? 'none' : 'inherit';
  }))
});
```

```html
<select id="1" class="form-control form-control-sm">
  <option></option>
  <option>Вариант 1</option>
  <option>Вариант 2</option>
  <option>Вариант 3</option>
</select>

<select id="2" class="form-control form-control-sm">
  <option></option>
  <option>Вариант 1</option>
  <option>Вариант 2</option>
  <option>Вариант 3</option>
</select>

<select id="3" class="form-control form-control-sm">
  <option></option>
  <option>Вариант 1</option>
  <option>Вариант 2</option>
  <option>Вариант 3</option>
</select>
```