# ранжирование по степени важности

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

есть пять вопросов, в каждом из них пять оценок, от одного до пяти. как реализовать что бы по  выборе в первом вопросе допустим 1,что бы данная оценка отсутствовала во втором вопросе, и  было уже от двух до пяти, и так со всеми вариантами. реализовать нужно на html jquery, is

```js
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
  // in the handler, 'this' refers to the box clicked on
  var $box = $(this);
  if ($box.is(":checked")) {
    // the name of the box is retrieved using the .attr() method
    // as it is assumed and expected to be immutable
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
    //console.log($(this).val());

    // the checked state of the group/box on the other hand will change
    // and the current value is retrieved using .prop() method
    $(group).prop("checked", false);
    $box.prop("checked", true);



    if ($(this).val() == 1) {

      $(".one").prop("disabled", "disabled");

      $(this).prop("disabled", false);
      //$("#radio-previous").val($(this).val());



    }
    if ($(this).val() == 2) {

      $(".two").prop("disabled", "disabled");
      $(this).prop("disabled", false);
      //$("#radio-previous").val($(this).val());
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 3) {
      $(".three").prop("disabled", "disabled");
      $(this).prop("disabled", false);
      $("#radio-previous").val($(this).val());
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 4) {
      $(".four").prop("disabled", "disabled");
      $(this).prop("disabled", false);
      $("#radio-previous").val($(this).val());
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 5) {
      $(".five").prop("disabled", "disabled");
      $(this).prop("disabled", false);
      $("#radio-previous").val($(this).val());
    }






  } else {
    $box.prop("checked", false);

    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
      $(".one").prop("disabled", false);
      //$(this).prop("disabled",false);
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 2) {
      $(".two").prop("disabled", false);
      //$(this).prop("disabled",false);
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 3) {
      $(".three").prop("disabled", false);
      //$(this).prop("disabled",false);
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 4) {
      $(".four").prop("disabled", false);
      //$(this).prop("disabled",false);
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 5) {
      $(".five").prop("disabled", false);
      //$(this).prop("disabled",false);
    }


  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3>Fruits</h3>
  <label>
        <input class="one" type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />Kiwi</label>
  <label>
        <input class="two" type="checkbox" class="radio" value="2" name="fooby[1][]" />Jackfruit</label>
  <label>
        <input class="three" type="checkbox" class="radio" value="3" name="fooby[1][]" />Mango</label>
  <label>
        <input class="four" type="checkbox" class="radio" value="4" name="fooby[1][]" />Mango</label>
  <label>
        <input class="five" type="checkbox" class="radio" value="5" name="fooby[1][]" />Mango</label>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Animals</h3>
  <label>
        <input class="one" type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[2][]" />Tiger</label>
  <label>
        <input class="two" type="checkbox" class="radio" value="2" name="fooby[2][]" />Sloth</label>
  <label>
        <input class="three" type="checkbox" class="radio" value="3" name="fooby[2][]" />Cheetah</label>
  <label>
        <input class="four" type="checkbox" class="radio" value="4" name="fooby[2][]" />Cheetah</label>
  <label>
        <input class="five" type="checkbox" class="radio" value="5" name="fooby[2][]" />Cheetah</label>

</div>
<div>
  <h3>Animals</h3>
  <label>
        <input class="one" type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[3][]" />Tiger</label>
  <label>
        <input class="two" type="checkbox" class="radio" value="2" name="fooby[3][]" />Sloth</label>
  <label>
        <input class="three" type="checkbox" class="radio" value="3" name="fooby[3][]" />Cheetah</label>
  <label>
        <input class="four" type="checkbox" class="radio" value="4" name="fooby[3][]" />Cheetah</label>
  <label>
        <input class="five" type="checkbox" class="radio" value="5" name="fooby[3][]" / >Cheetah</label>
  <input type="hidden" id="radio-previous" name="radio-previous" />
</div>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/985447/188366

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @РустамГимранов код добавил, проблема в том что при смене чекбокса  в категории он не разблокировывает то что было выбрано до этого

Comment: @StrangerintheQ буду благодарен если посомтире мой пример с чекбоксами , и как сделать что бы разблокировывались элементы при смене чекбокса

Comment: Перепишите текст вопроса, ниче не понятно.